# How to check whether a string is a first occurrence in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

If I have a series as below,
s= ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', Watermelon, 'Apple', 'Banana']

If I iterate through this series then I would like to know whether 'Apple' at index 1 is the first occurrence or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you posted is a simple `list`, not a PANDAS series.

In this case, just use the `index` command; it returns the index of the first occurrence.

```
if s.index("Apple") == 1:
    # The first occerrence, is, indeed at position 1
else:
    # No, it isn't ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s= ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Banana']
temp = set()
ans = []
for item in s:
    if item not in temp:
        temp.add(item)
        ans.append(True)
    else:
        ans.append(False)
print(ans)
>>> [True, False, True, True, False, False]
```